# How to replace Finder.app with any other file viewer?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, finder, customization, macvim

Is it possible to replace Finder.app with any other file viewer apps such as:

- [Marta.sh](https://marta.sh/)
- [Pathfinder](https://www.cocoatech.io/)
- [Forklift](https://binarynights.com/)

I'd love to use a more customizable file viewer alternative that would allow me to use Vim-like hotkeys for navigation.

Comment: Is your key item that you want Vim-like hotkeys? Investigate Keyboard Maestro along with a bit of AppleScript. Personally, I can't think of anything much worse than Vim like navigation, but can understand you might like it!

Comment: Did you see "Vim like navigation keys for Finder" in the related links on the right?

Comment: @Gilby Yes, I saw Vim-like navigation keys for Finder, but the answer of it did not satisfy my needs, thus I created this question that still remains unanswered.

The answer in Vim-like navigation keys for Finder claims that: 'it MAY be better to stick with mouse in a graphical environment' and continues to name how you can use Vim elsewhere e.g., IDE, Chrome. Personally, I use Vim controls in Intellij and Chrome. 

Will try Keyboard Maestro, but I cover its use-case with Raycast that is free. https://www.raycast.com/